# How to customize customize alerts + other metrics in pandas_profiling / y_data_profiling alerts

Tags: pyspark, pandas-profiling, data-profiling

pandas_profiling, or as it is now called, y_data_profiling provides a detailed breakdown of data quality.
How can we customize alerts + other metrics included in their default report?

I see options to change color scheme, and to hide existing measures. However, I dont see a way to add new metrics, particularly customized alerts.

I've tried researching this across the net, but haven't found any examples of how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Since that's a new feature, I would advise you to ask directly in their [community](https://datacentricai.community/). If it's not possible, the team might prioritize it as a new feature.